# How to style annotation lines in Google Charts?

Tags: annotations, google-visualization

I am using `Google Charts API` to display a vertical line on a `LineChart` (at a specific point) using `annotations`.

**Is it possible to style the annotation line, to make it more visible** (change its color/thickness, in case I add some vertical `gridlines` etc.)?

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lipa.png)

I'm only interested in the *annotation **line** style*, not in the *annotation text style*, as asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185308/how-to-change-color-of-annotation-text-in-google-charts) question.

I have the following code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn('number', '');
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'boolean',
    role: 'certainty'
    });

  data.addRows([
    ["-6", null, 1, true],
    ["-5", null, 2, true],
    ["-4", null, 4, true],
    ["-3", null, 8, true],
    ["-2", null, 7, true],
    ["-1", null, 7, true],
    ["0", '', 8, true],
    ["1", null, 4, false],
    ["2", null, 2, false],
    ["3", null, 3, false],
    ["4", null, 3, false],
    ["5", null, 1, false],
    ["6", null, 1, false]
  ]);

  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
draw(data, {
      curveType: 'function',
      width: 500,
      height: 400,
      annotations: {
        style: 'line'
      }
  });
}
```

You can play with the code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NC37X/284/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**first**, recommend using `loader.js` to load the library (vs. `jsapi`)

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

this will change the `load` statement, nothing else...

**next**, to change the annotation line color, use the following config option...

`annotations.stem.color`

although no option exists for *line thickness*, it can be changed manually,
when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

the annotation is drawn using a `<rect>` element

just need a way to find it in the dom

the following working snippet uses the annotation line color,
to find the annotation `<rect>` and change the width

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn('number', '');
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'boolean',
    role: 'certainty'
  });

  data.addRows([
    ["-6", null, 1, true],
    ["-5", null, 2, true],
    ["-4", null, 4, true],
    ["-3", null, 8, true],
    ["-2", null, 7, true],
    ["-1", null, 7, true],
    ["0", '', 8, true],
    ["1", null, 4, false],
    ["2", null, 2, false],
    ["3", null, 3, false],
    ["4", null, 3, false],
    ["5", null, 1, false],
    ["6", null, 1, false]
  ]);

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);

  var annotationColor = '#ff00ff';

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
      if (rect.getAttribute('fill') === annotationColor) {
        rect.setAttribute('width', '8');
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        color: annotationColor
      },
      style: 'line'
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: how to set different colours for multiple annotations

Comment: use the `series` option, if you would please add a question, would be happy to provide an example...